# Is it possible to automatically break into the debugger when a exception is thrown?

Tags: python, exception

If ones catches an exception outside of the function it is originally thrown, ones loses access to the local stack. As a result one cannot inspect the values of the variables that might have caused the exception.

Is there a way to automatically start break into the debugger (`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) whenever a exception is thrown to inspect the local stack?

Comment: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` our favorite line ❤️

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in an answer to [What is the simplest way of using Python pdb to inspect the cause of an unhandled exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12690039/380038)

> Wrap it with that:
>
> ```
> def debug_on(*exceptions):
>     if not exceptions:
>         exceptions = (AssertionError, )
>     def decorator(f):
>         @functools.wraps(f)
>         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
>             try:
>                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
>             except exceptions:
>                 pdb.post_mortem(sys.exc_info()[2])
>         return wrapper
>     return decorator
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> @debug_on(TypeError)
> def buggy_function()
>     ....
>     raise TypeError
> ```

Comment: global name 'functools' is not defined

Comment: @KardiTeknomo `import functools`, yeah, it's missing in the example

Answer (score 37):

You don't want to break on every exception; idiomatic Python code uses exceptions heavily (EAFP) so you'd be continually breaking in unrelated code.

Instead, use [pdb post-mortem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.pm): `import pdb; pdb.pm()`.  This uses `sys.last_traceback` to inspect the stack including the locals at the throw point.

Comment: Thanks, I works perfectly in the interpreter like in the example in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger), but how do I do it inside my script?

Comment: @Framester You put it in the script, where you want it to break.  `pdb.set_trace()` like you have in the question should work as well, it's what I usually use (not sure what the difference is)

Comment: A more interesting question statement would be "automatically catch uncaught exceptions that would blow up the program", supposing there is a precise way to define that.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I'll decide what I want to do.

Comment: Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.last_traceback) for `sys.last_traceback` states that "These three variables are not always defined;" In such case, using [`pdb.post_mortem`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pdb.html?highlight=pdb#pdb.post_mortem) sometimes helps.

Answer (score 29):

ipython supports this (http://ipython.org). from inside ipython, do

```
%pdb on
```

and from then on, it will automatically drop you inside the debugger whenever you get an exception.

note that you'll (probably) quickly tire of this in general use... every time you mistype something and get a syntax error, you'll have to exit the debugger. but it's sometimes useful.

Answer (score 23):

For python 3 (today at 3.8), this can be done with

```
python3 -m pdb myscript.py
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html):

> When invoked as a script, pdb will automatically enter post-mortem
> debugging if the program being debugged exits abnormally. After
> post-mortem debugging (or after normal exit of the program), pdb will
> restart the program. Automatic restarting preserves pdb’s state (such
> as breakpoints) and in most cases is more useful than quitting the
> debugger upon program’s exit.

Note that at launch, python will directly enter pdb mode, and you need to type `c` then `enter` to start running the script

Comment: It will start an equivalent of `pdb.post_mortem()`. Is there a way to start `pdb.set_trace()` instead? Or `ipdb.set_trace()`?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old and an answer has already been accepted, but I found this useful (for IPython):
start IPython with the --pdb option

```
ipython --pdb <whatever command>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wrap only some inner part of a function, or would need to decorate multiple functions otherwise, a context manager could be used as an alternative to the accepted answer. I am now using this simple version that catches all exceptions. I recommend using `pudb`, but this will work `pdb` or any other debugger too

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def postmortem_pudb():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as exc:
        import pudb
        pudb.post_mortem()
```

Use like this

```py
with postmortem_pudb():
    function_that_might_throw_some()
    ...
    another_function_that_might_throw_some()
    ...
    yet_another_function_that_might_throw_some()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ipython` with `--pdb` flag to debug.

Note that all other arguments should be put after an extra `--` (before `--data` in the example below).

For example, to debug `my_python_file.py`, we can open Terminal, then:

```
ipython --pdb my_python_file.py -- --dataset my_dataset --num_epochs 10
```

To quit the debug session, simply type `q`.

---

Another option is to use `python -m pdb`, e.g., `python -m pdb my_python_file.py --dataset my_dataset --num_epochs 10`