# Is it possible to change PyTest's assert statement behaviour in Python

Tags: python, testing, pytest, assert

I am using Python assert statements to match the actual and expected behaviour. I do not have a control over these as if there is an error test cases aborts. I want to take control of assertion error and want to define if I want to abort testcase on failure assert or not.

Also I want to add something like if there is an assertion error then test case should be paused and user can resume at any moment.

I do not have any idea how to do this

Code example, we are using pytest here

```
import pytest
def test_abc():
    a = 10
    assert a == 10, "some error message"
```

`Below is my expectation`

When assert throws an assertionError, i should have a option of pausing the testcase and can debug and later resume. For pause and resume I will use `tkinter` module. I will make a assert function as below

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

top = tkinter.Tk()

def _assertCustom(assert_statement, pause_on_fail = 0):
    #assert_statement will be something like: assert a == 10, "Some error"
    #pause_on_fail will be derived from global file where I can change it on runtime
    if pause_on_fail == 1:
        try:
            eval(assert_statement)
        except AssertionError as e:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(e)
            eval (assert_statement)
            #Above is to raise the assertion error again to fail the testcase
    else:
        eval (assert_statement)
```

Going forward I have to change every assert statement with this function as

```
import pytest
def test_abc():
    a = 10
    # Suppose some code and below is the assert statement 
    _assertCustom("assert a == 10, 'error message'")
```

This is too much effort for me as I have to make change at thousand of places where I have used assert. Is there any easy way to do that in `pytest`

`Summary:` I needs something where I can pause the testcase on failure and then resume after debugging. I know about `tkinter` and that is the reason I have used it. Any other ideas will be welcomes

`Note`: Above code is not tested yet. There may be small syntax errors too

Edit: Thanks for the answers. Extending this question a little ahead now. What if I want change the behaviour of assert. Currently when there is an assertion error testcase exits. What if I want to choose if I need testcase exit on particular assert failure or not. I don't want to write custom assert function as mentioned above because this way I have to change at number of places

Comment: Could you give us a code example of what you'd like to do?

Comment: Don't use `assert` but write your own checking functions that do what you want.

Comment: Why dont you insert *assert* in *try* block and the error message in *except*?

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is to use `pytest` for your test cases. It supports using [assert](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html) and [skipping tests](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html) along with many more features that make writing test suites easier.

Comment: Wouldn't it be pretty straightforward to write a simple tool that would mechanically replace every `assert cond, "msg"` in your code with `_assertCustom("assert cond, 'msg'")`?  Probably a `sed` one-liner could do it.

Comment: @NPE: Does pytest gives any inbuilt option of doing this where I can change the behaviour of assert statements

Comment: I wonder whether you can do something with a debugger? In gdb you could do `catch throw` to stop as soon as an exception is raised. It seems pdb does not support something like that but people have worked around that: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960242/is-it-possible-to-automatically-break-into-the-debugger-when-a-exception-is-thro and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242485/starting-python-debugger-automatically-on-error

Comment: Seriously use an IDE! When you're trying to find new language features because you can't do a find and replace, something is horribly wrong!

Comment: You can't change the behavior of assert statements without patching pytest.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are using `pytest`, which gives you ample options to interact with failing tests. It gives you command line options and and several hooks to make this possible. I'll explain how to use each and where you could make customisations to fit your specific debugging needs.

I'll also go into more exotic options that would allow you to skip specific assertions entirely, if you really feel you must.

### Handle exceptions, not assert

Note that a failing test doesn’t normally stop pytest; only if you enabled the [explicitly tell it to exit after a certain number of failures](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/failures.html#stopping-after-the-first-or-n-failures). Also, tests fail because an exception is raised; `assert` raises [`AssertionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError) but that’s not the only exception that’ll cause a test to fail! You want to control how exceptions are handled, not alter `assert`.

However, a failing assert *will* end the individual test. That's because once an exception is raised outside of a `try...except` block, Python unwinds the current function frame, and there is no going back on that.

I don't think that that's what you want, judging by your description of your `_assertCustom()` attempts to re-run the assertion, but I'll discuss your options further down nonetheless.

### Post-mortem debugging in pytest with pdb

For the various options to handle failures in a debugger, I'll start with the [`--pdb` command-line switch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#dropping-to-pdb-python-debugger-on-failures), which opens the standard debugging prompt when a test fails (output elided for brevity):

```bash
$ mkdir demo
$ touch demo/__init__.py
$ cat << EOF > demo/test_foo.py
> def test_ham():
>     assert 42 == 17
> def test_spam():
>     int("Vikings")
> EOF
$ pytest demo/test_foo.py --pdb
[ ... ]
test_foo.py:2: AssertionError
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entering PDB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /.../demo/test_foo.py(2)test_ham()
-> assert 42 == 17
(Pdb) q
Exit: Quitting debugger
[ ... ]
```

With this switch, when a test fails pytest starts a [*post-mortem* debugging session](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem). This is essentially exactly what you wanted; to stop the code at the point of a failed test and open the debugger to take a look at the state of your test. You can interact with the local variables of the test, the globals, and the locals and globals of every frame in the stack.

Here pytest gives you full control over whether or not to exit after this point: if you use the `q` quit command then pytest exits the run too, using `c` for continue will return control to pytest and the next test is executed.

### Using an alternative debugger

You are not bound to the `pdb` debugger for this; you can set a different debugger with the `--pdbcls` switch. Any [`pdb.Pdb()` compatible](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.Pdb) implementation would work, including the [IPython debugger implementation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.debugger.html#IPython.core.debugger.Pdb), or [most other Python debuggers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools#Debuggers) (the [pudb debugger](https://pypi.org/project/pudb/) requires the `-s` switch is used, or a [special plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pudb/)). The switch takes a module and class, e.g. to use `pudb` you could use:

```bash
$ pytest -s --pdb --pdbcls=pudb.debugger:Debugger
```

You could use this feature to write your own wrapper class around `Pdb` that simply returns immediately if the specific failure is not something you are interested in. `pytest` uses `Pdb()` exactly like [`pdb.post_mortem()` does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b1fc8c0c8aec7ef8edd119034e076bc48882ffbb/Lib/pdb.py#L1615-L1627):

> ```
> p = Pdb()
> p.reset()
> p.interaction(None, t)
> ```

Here, `t` is a [traceback object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#traceback-objects). When `p.interaction(None, t)` returns, `pytest` continues with the next test, *unless* `p.quitting` is set to `True` (at which point pytest then exits).

Here is an example implementation that prints out that we are declining to debug and returns immediately, unless the test raised `ValueError`, saved as `demo/custom_pdb.py`:

```py
import pdb, sys
    
class CustomPdb(pdb.Pdb):
    def interaction(self, frame, traceback):
        if sys.last_type is not None and not issubclass(sys.last_type, ValueError):
            print("Sorry, not interested in this failure")
            return
        return super().interaction(frame, traceback)
```

When I use this with the above demo, this is output (again, elided for brevity):

```bash
$ pytest test_foo.py -s --pdb --pdbcls=demo.custom_pdb:CustomPdb
[ ... ]
    def test_ham():
>       assert 42 == 17
E       assert 42 == 17

test_foo.py:2: AssertionError
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entering PDB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Sorry, not interested in this failure
F
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> traceback >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    def test_spam():
>       int("Vikings")
E       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Vikings'

test_foo.py:4: ValueError
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entering PDB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /.../test_foo.py(4)test_spam()
-> int("Vikings")
(Pdb)
```

The above introspects [`sys.last_type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.last_type) to determine if the failure is 'interesting'.

However, I can't really recommend this option unless you want to write your own debugger using tkInter or something similar. Note that that is a big undertaking.

### Filtering failures; pick and choose when to open the debugger

The next level up is the [pytest *debugging and interaction* hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#debugging-interaction-hooks); these are hook points for behaviour customisations, to replace or enhance how pytest normally handles things like handling an exception or entering the debugger via [`pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) or [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) (Python 3.7 or newer).

The internal implementation of this hook is responsible for printing the `>>> entering PDB >>>` banner above as well, so using this hook to prevent the debugger from running means you won't see this output at all. You can have your own hook then delegate to the original hook when a test failure is 'interesting', and so filter test failures *independent* of the debugger you are using! You can access the internal implementation by [accessing it by name](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#accessing-another-plugin-by-name); the internal hook plugin for this is named `pdbinvoke`. To prevent it from running you need to *unregister* it but save a reference do we can call it directly as needed.

Here is a sample implementation of such a hook; you can put this in [any of the locations plugins are loaded from](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#plugin-discovery-order-at-tool-startup); I put it in `demo/conftest.py`:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    # unregister returns the unregistered plugin
    pdbinvoke = config.pluginmanager.unregister(name="pdbinvoke")
    if pdbinvoke is None:
        # no --pdb switch used, no debugging requested
        return
    # get the terminalreporter too, to write to the console
    tr = config.pluginmanager.getplugin("terminalreporter")
    # create or own plugin
    plugin = ExceptionFilter(pdbinvoke, tr)

    # register our plugin, pytest will then start calling our plugin hooks
    config.pluginmanager.register(plugin, "exception_filter")

class ExceptionFilter:
    def __init__(self, pdbinvoke, terminalreporter):
        # provide the same functionality as pdbinvoke
        self.pytest_internalerror = pdbinvoke.pytest_internalerror
        self.orig_exception_interact = pdbinvoke.pytest_exception_interact
        self.tr = terminalreporter

    def pytest_exception_interact(self, node, call, report):
        if not call.excinfo. errisinstance(ValueError):
            self.tr.write_line("Sorry, not interested!")
            return
        return self.orig_exception_interact(node, call, report)
```

The above plugin uses the internal [`TerminalReporter` plugin](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/14142b911377d5354acf07ca1c9a7f11e9298b84/src/_pytest/terminal.py#L218-L942) to write out lines to the terminal; this makes the output cleaner when using the default compact test status format, and lets you write things to the terminal even with output capturing enabled.

The example registers the plugin object with `pytest_exception_interact` hook via another hook, [`pytest_configure()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure), but making sure it runs late enough (using [`@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#hook-function-ordering-call-example)) to be able to un-register the internal `pdbinvoke` plugin. When the hook is called, the example tests against the [`call.exceptinfo` object](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#exceptioninfo); you can also check the [node](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.nodes.Node) or the [report](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#testreport) too.

With the above sample code in place in `demo/conftest.py`, the `test_ham` test failure is ignored, only the `test_spam` test failure, which raises `ValueError`, results in the debug prompt opening:

```bash
$ pytest demo/test_foo.py --pdb
[ ... ]
demo/test_foo.py F
Sorry, not interested!

demo/test_foo.py F
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> traceback >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    def test_spam():
>       int("Vikings")
E       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Vikings'

demo/test_foo.py:4: ValueError
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entering PDB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /.../demo/test_foo.py(4)test_spam()
-> int("Vikings")
(Pdb)
```

To re-iterate, the above approach has the added advantage that you can combine this with *any debugger that works with pytest*, including pudb, or the IPython debugger:

```bash
$ pytest demo/test_foo.py --pdb --pdbcls=IPython.core.debugger:Pdb
[ ... ]
demo/test_foo.py F
Sorry, not interested!

demo/test_foo.py F
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> traceback >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    def test_spam():
>       int("Vikings")
E       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Vikings'

demo/test_foo.py:4: ValueError
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entering PDB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /.../demo/test_foo.py(4)test_spam()
      1 def test_ham():
      2     assert 42 == 17
      3 def test_spam():
----> 4     int("Vikings")

ipdb>
```

It also has much more context about what test was being run (via the `node` argument) and direct access to the exception raised (via the `call.excinfo` `ExceptionInfo` instance).

Note that specific pytest debugger plugins (such as `pytest-pudb` or `pytest-pycharm`) register their own `pytest_exception_interact` hooksp. A more complete implementation would have to loop over all plugins in the plugin-manager to override arbitrary plugins, automatically, using [`config.pluginmanager.list_name_plugin`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pluggy.PluginManager.list_name_plugin) and `hasattr()` to test each plugin.

### Making failures go away altogether

While this gives you full control over failed test debugging, this still leaves the test as *failed* even if you opted not to open the debugger for a given test. If you want to make failures go away altogether, you can make use a different hook: [`pytest_runtest_call()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_call).

When pytest runs tests, it'll run the test via the above hook, which is expected to return `None` or raise an exception. From this a report is created, optionally a log entry is created, and if the test failed, the aforementioned `pytest_exception_interact()` hook is called. So all you need to do is change what the result that this hook produces; instead of an exception it should just not return anything at all.

The best way to do that is to use a [*hook wrapper*](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#hookwrapper-executing-around-other-hooks). Hook wrappers don't have to do the actual work, but instead are given a chance to alter what happens to the result of a hook. All you have to do is add the line:

```
outcome = yield
```

in your hook wrapper implementation and you get access to the [hook result](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#result), including the test exception via `outcome.excinfo`. This attribute is set to a tuple of (type, instance, traceback) if an exception was raised in the test. Alternatively, you could call [`outcome.get_result()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pluggy.callers._Result.get_result) and use standard `try...except` handling.

So how do you make a failed test pass? You have 3 basic options:

- You could mark the test as an *expected* failure, by calling [`pytest.xfail()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-xfail) in the wrapper.
- You could mark the item as *skipped*, which pretends that the test was never run in the first place, by calling [`pytest.skip()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-skip).
- You could remove the exception, by using the [`outcome.force_result()` method](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pluggy.callers._Result.force_result); set the result to an empty list here (meaning: the registered hook produced nothing but `None`), and the exception is cleared entirely.

What you use is up to you. Do make sure to check the result for skipped and expected-failure tests first as you don't need to handle those cases as if the test failed. You can access the special exceptions these options raise via `pytest.skip.Exception` and `pytest.xfail.Exception`.

Here's an example implementation which marks failed tests that don't raise `ValueError`, as *skipped*:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    outcome = yield
    try:
        outcome.get_result()
    except (pytest.xfail.Exception, pytest.skip.Exception, pytest.exit.Exception):
        raise  # already xfailed,  skipped or explicit exit
    except ValueError:
        raise  # not ignoring
    except (pytest.fail.Exception, Exception):
        # turn everything else into a skip
        pytest.skip("[NOTRUN] ignoring everything but ValueError")
```

When put in `conftest.py` the output becomes:

```bash
$ pytest -r a demo/test_foo.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.0, pytest-3.10.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: ..., inifile:
collected 2 items

demo/test_foo.py sF                                                      [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_spam ___________________________________

    def test_spam():
>       int("Vikings")
E       ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Vikings'

demo/test_foo.py:4: ValueError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAIL demo/test_foo.py::test_spam
SKIP [1] .../demo/conftest.py:12: [NOTRUN] ignoring everything but ValueError
===================== 1 failed, 1 skipped in 0.07 seconds ======================
```

I used the `-r a` flag to make it clearer that `test_ham` was skipped now.

If you replace the `pytest.skip()` call with `pytest.xfail("[XFAIL] ignoring everything but ValueError")`, the test is marked as an expected failure:

```bash
[ ... ]
XFAIL demo/test_foo.py::test_ham
  reason: [XFAIL] ignoring everything but ValueError
[ ... ]
```

and using `outcome.force_result([])` marks it as passed:

```bash
$ pytest -v demo/test_foo.py  # verbose to see individual PASSED entries
[ ... ]
demo/test_foo.py::test_ham PASSED                                        [ 50%]
```

It's up to you which one you feel fits your use case best. For `skip()` and `xfail()` I mimicked the standard message format (prefixed with `[NOTRUN]` or `[XFAIL]`) but you are free to use any other message format you want.

In all three cases pytest will not open the debugger for tests whose outcome you altered using this method.

### Altering individual assert statements

If you want to alter `assert` tests *within a test*, then you are setting yourself up for a whole lot more work. Yes, this is *technically* possible, but only by rewriting the very code that Python is going to execute *at compile time*.

When you use `pytest`, this is actually *already being done*. Pytest [rewrites `assert` statements to give you more context when your asserts fail](https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.1/assert.html#assert-details); see [this blog post](http://pybites.blogspot.com/2011/07/behind-scenes-of-pytests-new-assertion.html) for a good overview of exactly what is being done, as well as the [`_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py` source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py). Note that that module is over 1k lines long, and requires that you understand how [Python's abstract syntax trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) work. If you do, you *could* monkeypatch that module to add your own modifications there, including surrounding the `assert` with a `try...except AssertionError:` handler.

**However**, you can't just disable or ignore asserts selectively, because subsequent statements could easily depend on state (specific object arrangements, variables set, etc.) that a skipped assert was meant to guard against. If an assert tests that `foo` is not `None`, then a later assert relies on `foo.bar` to exist, then you simply will run into an `AttributeError` there, etc. Do stick to re-raising the exception, if you need to go this route.

I'm not going to go into further detail on rewriting `asserts` here, as I don't think this is worth pursuing, not given the amount of work involved, and with post-mortem debugging giving you access to the state of the test at the point of assertion failure *anyway*.

Note that if you do want to do this, you don't need to use `eval()` (which wouldn't work anyway, `assert` is a statement, so you'd need to use `exec()` instead), nor would you have to run the assertion twice (which can lead to issues if the expression used in the assertion altered state). You would instead embed the `ast.Assert` node inside a `ast.Try` node, and attach an except handler that uses an empty `ast.Raise` node re-raise the exception that was caught.

#### Using the debugger to skip assertion statements.

The Python debugger actually lets you *skip statements*, using the [`j` / `jump` command](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-jump). If you know *up front* that a specific assertion *will* fail, you can use this to bypass it. You could run your tests with `--trace`, which opens the debugger *at the start of every test*, then issue a `j <line after assert>` to skip it when the debugger is paused just before the assert.

You can even automate this. Using the above techniques you can build a custom debugger plugin that

- uses the `pytest_testrun_call()` hook to catch the `AssertionError` exception
- extracts the line 'offending' line number from the traceback, and perhaps with some source code analysis determines the line numbers before and after the assertion required to execute a successful jump
- runs the test *again*, but this time using a `Pdb` subclass that sets a breakpoint on the line before the assert, and automatically executes a jump to the second when the breakpoint is hit, followed by a `c` continue.

Or, instead of waiting for an assertion to fail, you could automate setting breakpoints for each `assert` found in a test (again using source code analysis, you can trivially extract line numbers for `ast.Assert` nodes in an an AST of the test), execute the asserted test using debugger scripted commands, and use the `jump` command to skip the assertion itself. You'd have to make a tradeoff; run all tests under a debugger (which is slow as the interpreter has to call a trace function for every statement) or only apply this to failing tests and pay the price of re-running those tests from scratch.

Such a plugin would be a lot of work to create, I'm not going to write an example here, partly because it wouldn't fit in an answer anyway, and partly because *I don't think it is worth the time*. I'd just open up the debugger and make the jump manually. A failing assert indicates a bug in either the test itself or the code-under-test, so you may as well just focus on debugging the problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve exactly what you want without absolutely any code modification with [pytest --pdb](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/usage.html?highlight=pdb#dropping-to-pdb-python-debugger-on-failures).

With your example:

```py
import pytest
def test_abc():
    a = 9
    assert a == 10, "some error message"
```

Run with --pdb:

```
py.test --pdb
```

```
collected 1 item

test_abc.py F
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> traceback >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    def test_abc():
        a = 9
>       assert a == 10, "some error message"
E       AssertionError: some error message
E       assert 9 == 10

test_abc.py:4: AssertionError
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entering PDB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /private/tmp/a/test_abc.py(4)test_abc()
-> assert a == 10, "some error message"
(Pdb) p a
9
(Pdb)
```

As soon as a test fails, you can debug it with the builtin python debugger. If you're done debugging, you can `continue` with the rest of the tests.

Comment: Will this stop when test case fails or test step fails.

Comment: Please check the linked docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#dropping-to-pdb-python-debugger-on-failures

Comment: Excellent idea. But if use --pdb, testcase will pause at every failure. can i decide at runtime at which failure I want to pause the test case

Answer (score 5):

If you're using PyCharm then you can add an Exception Breakpoint to pause execution whenever an assert fails. Select View Breakpoints (CTRL-SHIFT-F8) and add an on-raise exception handler for AssertionError. Note that this may slow down the execution of the tests.

Otherwise, if you don't mind pausing at the *end* of each failing test (just before it errors) rather than at the point the assertion fails, then you have a few options. Note however that by this point various cleanup code, such as closing files that were opened in the test, might have already been run. Possible options are:

1. You can tell pytest to drop you into the debugger on errors using the [--pdb option](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#dropping-to-pdb-python-debugger-on-failures).
2. You can define the following decorator and decorate each relevant test function with it. (Apart from logging a message, you could also start a [pdb.post_mortem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem) at this point, or even an interactive [code.interact](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.interact) with the locals of the frame where the exception originated, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/242514/1900954).)

```
from functools import wraps

def pause_on_assert(test_func):
    @wraps(test_func)
    def test_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            test_func(*args, **kwargs)
        except AssertionError as e:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(e)
            # re-raise exception to make the test fail
            raise
    return test_wrapper

@pause_on_assert
def test_abc()
    a = 10
    assert a == 2, "some error message"
```

3. If you don't want to manually decorate every test function, you can instead define an autouse fixture that inspects [sys.last_value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.last_value):

```
import sys

@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def pause_on_assert():
    yield
    if hasattr(sys, 'last_value') and isinstance(sys.last_value, AssertionError):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(sys.last_value)
```

Comment: I liked the answer with decorators but It cannot be done dynamically. I want to dynamically control when I want to pause_on_assert or not. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Dynamic in what way? As in a single switch to enable/disable it everywhere? Or some way to control it for each test?

Comment: Suppose I am running some testcases. In the middle I got the need of pause on failure. I will enable the switch. Later any point of time I feel that I need to disable the switch.

Comment: Your decorator in answer:2 will not work for me because my test case will have multiple asserts

Comment: Regarding a 'switch', you can update either implementation of `pause_on_assert` to read from a file to decide whether to pause or not.

Comment: Deviating from the question. Assert here aborts the testcase as it raises AssertionError. I want something like if I need testcase will proceed to next step on assertion Failure. Is it possible without doing much changes in the code?

Comment: That's more complicated, since a failed assert expression will always terminate execution. It __may__ be possible with an import hook that modifies the code on the fly, but by far the easiest is to rewrite the code to use a custom assert function. Still, I'll have a think.

Comment: How is it possible to achieve when I need the testcase to continue when assert fails

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution, if you're willing to use Visual Studio Code, could be to use [conditional breakpoints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_conditional-breakpoints).

This would allow you to set up your assertions, for example:

```
import pytest
def test_abc():
    a = 10
    assert a == 10, "some error message"
```

Then add a conditional breakpoint in your assert line which will only break when your assertion fails:

[image]

Comment: @Nitesh - I think this solution solves all your problems, you only break when an assertion fails, you can debug the code there and then and you can continue with the remaining tests afterwards... Albeit it is a little more cumbersome to set up initially