# Any command like '%debug' (in jupyter) when running python script?

Tags: python

In jupyter, when an error occurs, we can continuously debug the error with the command `%debug`. I want to know if there is the similar way in running python script (.py) in the shell.

I know that I can use pdb to make some break points, but I just want to know the way without such a pre-processing (because re-running the code until the error costs a lot of time).

Comment: `pdb` used post mortem seems like the preferred way in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960242/is-it-possible-to-automatically-break-into-the-debugger-when-a-exception-is-thro/18962528

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no: it depends on "the shell" that you are running.  Jupyter launches with a *lot* of instrumentation in support of its debugger, assuming that you're using Jupyter because you want those capabilities at the ready.

I presume that you're using some UNIX shell (since you mention `pdb`); implicitly loading superfluous software is antithetical to the UNIX philosophy.

I think that what you'll need is one of the "after" debugger modes, although that will still leave you without information from just before the error point: those packages cannot do much to trace the history of problem variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can u give me some examples of 'those packages cannot do much to trace the history of problem variables' if u know some of them.