# python: run interactive python shell from program

Tags: python, debugging

I often have the case that I'll be writing a script, and I'm up to a part of the script where I want to play around with some of the variables interactively. Getting to that part requires running a large part of the script I've already written.

In this case it isn't trivial to run this program from inside the shell. I would have to recreate the conditions of that function somehow.

What I want to do is call a function, like `runshell()`, which will run the python shell at that point in the program, keeping all variables in scope, allowing me to poke around in it.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you talking about using the Python debugger?  Or are you looking for design advice on how to decompose a large script into more manageable pieces?

Comment: i'm asking about the former - i had forgotten that word ('debugger')!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jump into a Python Interactive Session mid-program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925832/jump-into-a-python-interactive-session-mid-program)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
import code

code.interact(local=locals())
```

But using the Python debugger is probably more what you want:

```
import pdb

pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: thanks! I am looking for this for a while! import code

Comment: If you're at a breakpoint in a PDB session, and you want to descend into an interactive Python shell from there, the `import code; code.interact(local=locals())` thing is perfect for that. Variables and functions defined in that interactive shell are then available when you hit ^D and return to the debugging session. Thanks very much, Michael Hoffman.

Comment: It works but does not support TAB auto-completion.

Answer (score 24):

By far the most convenient method that I have found is:

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

You get all your global and local variables and all the creature comforts of IPython: tab completion, auto indenting, etc.

You have to install the IPython module to use it of course:

```
pip install ipython
```

Comment: I love this with one caveat. I have to redo my imports. Any way to pass through the the imports to the new interactive shell as well?

Answer (score 6):

For practicality I'd like to add that you can put the debugger trace in a one liner:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Which is a nice line to add to an editor that supports snippets, like TextMate or Vim+SnipMate. I have it set up to expand "break" into the above one liner.

Comment: yep this is indeed what I end up doing nowadays

Answer (score 5):

You can use the python debugger ([pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)) [set_trace](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) function.

For example, if you invoke a script like this:

```
def whatever():
    x = 3
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    whatever()
```

You get the scope at the point when set_trace is called:

```
$ python ~/test/test.py
--Return--
> /home/jterrace/test/test.py(52)whatever()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) x
3
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a perfect source but I've written a few manhole's before, here is one I wrote for an abandoned pet project http://code.google.com/p/devdave/source/browse/pymethius/trunk/webmud/handlers/konsole.py

And here is one from the Twisted Library http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.1.0/twisted/manhole/telnet.py  the console logic is in Shell.doCommand