# How to parse flags to a Python executable?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

if I have a python executable `hello_world.py` e.g.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
print 'hello world!'
```

which I call via

```
chmod u=rwx hello_world.py
./hello_world.py
```

which works as expected, but... how can I parse interpreter flags to it such that I can run it in interactive mode or not? e.g.

```
./hello_world.py -i
>>>
```

I know that I can edit the shebang so certain flags are passed e.g. `#!/opt/local/bin/python -i -d` but I would like a dynamic way to control these flags which can be entered when running the executable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. rename `/opt/local/bin/python` to `/opt/local/bin/python2`
2. create a shellscript that parses your flags and calls `python2`. name it `/opt/local/bin/python`
3. profit

although thats going to be a pain if you are trying to distribute your script with those options

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the -i flag in `sys.argv` (possibly using the `argparse` module).

Then use `code.interact` or `pdb.set_trace()` to enable the interactive mode.

Generally, your script should be structured like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    # the actual script code
    ...
    if '-i' in sys.argv[1:]:  # or something equivalent
        import code
        local=locals() # or any variables you want to have available
        code.interact(local=local)
```

Tips:

- Try to keep the if-block lightweight and keep the script logic in module-level functions - this gets useful during testing.)
- `#!/usr/bin/env python` is the conventional cross-platform way of finding the python executable.

See also: [python: run interactive python shell from program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677312/python-run-interactive-python-shell-from-program)