# Python command to jump into interactive mode from a script

Tags: python, ipython, pdb

I have a python script that runs and accepts user input to make decisions.  Based on the input I would like to give the user control of the python repl.  Here is an example:

```
def func():
    # hand over control to the user
    breakpoint()

while True:
    print('What would you like to do?\nq: quit\ni: interact')
    i = input()
    if i=='q':
        break
    elif i=='i':
        func()
    else:
        print(f'invalid command: {i}')
```

Calling this code snippet with for example ipython3, the user is prompted for input. When the user presses i, `func()` is called, at which point I would like the user to be able to type python commands such as print(i).

My current best solution is to then set a breakpoint, the user may then need to type `r` to get to the right frame and then must then type `interact`.  This is nearly acceptable, but I would like my user to not need to know that I'm using a debugger to give them interactive control, rather I would like them to be given an ipython prompt directly.

I looked at this post from 10 years ago: [Jump into a Python Interactive Session mid-program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925832/jump-into-a-python-interactive-session-mid-program) rz.'s comment looks interesting, but it looks like too much has changed for me to use his answer as is, plus there may be newer ways of doing things.