# Starting debugger on errors in threads

Tags: python

I'm using following trick to get debugger started on error
[Starting python debugger automatically on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242485/starting-python-debugger-automatically-on-error)

Any idea how to make this also work for errors that happen in newly created threads? I'm using thread pool, something like http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool/

Answer (score 2):

I'd say inject that code in the beginning of each Thread's run().

If you don't want to change that code, you could do monkeypatch it e.g. like this:

```
Worker.run = lambda *a: [init_pdb(), Worker.run(*a)][-1]
```

Or like this:

```
def wrapper(*a):
    # init pdb here
    Worker.run(*a)

Worker.run = wrapper
```

If you wanna go real hardcore, you can override threading.Thread.start, or possibly threading.Thread altogether before you import other modules, e.g.:

```
class DebuggedThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DebuggedThread, self).__init__()
        self._real_run = self.run
        self.run = self._debug_run
    def _debug_run(self):
        # initialize debugger here
        self._real_run()

threading.Thread = DebuggedThread
```