# Python - start interactive debugger when exception would be otherwise thrown

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Is there any way to make a python program start an interactive debugger, like what `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` instead of actually throwing an exception?

I know the difficulty of making this work, but it would be much more valuable than a huge stack trace after which I have to use to figure out where to insert breakpoints and then restart the program to debug it. I know that simply making the debugger start instead of throwing an exception would not make sense because any exception can be caught at a level or another, so *if I could just select a list of exceptions for which an interactive debug session would start **instead** of them being thrown* (because I know the exceptions in this list would really be "errors" and no meaningful program behavior could follow afterwards)...

I've heard that Common Lisp has something like this, but I don't know how it works exactly, just that "true lispers" praise it a lot...

Comment: This question looks very similar to: [Starting python debugger automatically on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242485/starting-python-debugger-automatically-on-error) which has better answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest way is to wrap your entire code inside a `try` block like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        raise Exception()
    except:
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
```

There is a more complicated solution which uses `sys.excepthook` to override the handling of uncaught exceptions, as described in  [this recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/65287-automatically-start-the-debugger-on-an-exception/):

```
## {{{ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65287/ (r5)
# code snippet, to be included in 'sitecustomize.py'
import sys

def info(type, value, tb):
   if hasattr(sys, 'ps1') or not sys.stderr.isatty():
      # we are in interactive mode or we don't have a tty-like
      # device, so we call the default hook
      sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tb)
   else:
      import traceback, pdb
      # we are NOT in interactive mode, print the exception...
      traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
      print
      # ...then start the debugger in post-mortem mode.
      pdb.pm()

sys.excepthook = info
## end of http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65287/ }}}
```

The above code should be included in a file called [`sitecustomize.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) inside `site-packages` directory, which is automatically imported by python. The debugger is only started when python is run in non-interactive mode.

Comment: referring to you second example, as this is what I mean, I don't want to have to modify existing program code: yeah, but what I'd like is to have the debugger dynamically insert a breakpoint and start the 'live' debugger *instead* of throwing the exception (prevent it from being thrown or smth) not 'post mortem'

Comment: @NeuronQ did you try to substitute `pdb.pm()` by `pdb.set_trace()`? This should work

Comment: @NeuroQ see my answer for how to do this without any system modification

Answer (score 11):

*This question is quite old, so this is mainly for future me*

```
try:
    ...
except:
    import traceback, pdb, sys
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ''
    pdb.post_mortem()
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot, I knew this was possible and it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [a package](https://pypi.org/project/mort/) to start pdb on exception. It takes @boreis-gorelik's answer, and modifies the interpreter state at runtime so no code changes are necessary:

## Installation

```
 pip install mort
```

## Usage

```
mort <file.py or module to execute>
```

When the exception occurs, the pdb repl should start in the given terminal

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside the REPL, you can do

```
import sys
import pdb
pdb.post_mortem(sys.last_traceback)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html