# Flask and sys.excepthook

Tags: python, exception, flask

I want to add global exception handling object to my Flask webproject. In main module, where application class is created I've added code to override `sys.excepthook`. Here is simple test code:

```
import sys

def my_exception_hook(exception_type, value, traceback):
    print "My exception handler"
    print "  Exception type:", exception_type
    print "  Exception instance:", value
    print "  Traceback:", traceback

    sys.__excepthook__(exception_type, value, traceback)

sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook

from flask import Flask
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    #Exception raised here "requests.exceptions.MissingSchema" not captured by my handler
    r = requests.get('ololo', auth=('user', 'pass'))
    return "Hello, world!"

#raise Exception("AAA") #Exception raised here is successfully goes to my_exception_hook

app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

I do not want and have no possibility to envelop each call or `requests` module with `try/catch`. Also I want to handle other eaception, for example, mongoDB connection problem which may occured spontaneousely (not wheen I creating connection), please do not suggest it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask already handles exceptions in views for you. Using `sys.excepthook` is **not** the right way to handle this, the hook will never be called.

Specify a custom exception handler with Flask instead, see the [Redirects and Errors section](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) of the Quickstart manual:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(500)
def page_not_found(error):
    return 'some error message'
```

Flask also uses the [`logging` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to record exceptions; configure the logging module to write anything of severity `logging.ERROR` to the console or a log file.

Since you use `app.run(debug=True, port=5001)`, you'll already see exceptions printed to the console.

Note that the 500 error page is only ever invoked when debug is **not** set to `True` however; otherwise the [Werkzeug debug view](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/) is invoked instead.

Comment: I am totally forgot about errorhandler's parameter. When paste `Exception` insteand of `500` all works as expected.

Comment: @AlexG.P.: Right, the 500 error handler only works when not in debug mode.