# FastAPI traceback formatting

Tags: python, fastapi, traceback

I am trying to format traceback into a single line in my fastAPI application, as the logs are getting distributed to different entries in cloudwatch/kibana. I have tried to use `sys.excepthook` approach as mentioned in the accepted answer [for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642111/can-i-make-python-output-exceptions-in-one-line-via-logging). But am still getting the same way. Can we update `sys` specific parameters like `sys.excepthook` from the fastAPI code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627429/flask-and-sys-excepthook

Comment: Have you seen https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers ?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have seen that, as I have some python asycio scripts which use the same config from the application, I am trying to use sys.excepthook which will have effect in both places