# Pandas: Location of a row with error

Tags: pandas

I am pretty new to Pandas and trying to find out where my code breaks. Say, I am doing a type conversion:

```
df['x']=df['x'].astype('int')
```

...and I get an error "ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '1.0692e+06'

In general, if I have 1000 entries in the dataframe, how can I find out what entry causes a break. Is there anything in ipdb to output the current location (i.e. where the code broke)? Basically, I am trying to pinpoint what value cannot be converted to Int.

Comment: If in ipython you can turn on `pdb` and start debugging: `%pdb` execute the command and then `%debug` you will then be able to walk the stack and display the values

Comment: @EdChum 's answer is best. You could also loop over the values and wrap in try/except.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error you are seeing might be due to the value(s) in the `x` column being strings:

```
In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['1.0692e+06']})
In [16]: df['x'].astype('int')
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '1.0692e+06'
```

Ideally, the problem can be avoided by making sure the values stored in the
DataFrame are already ints not strings *when the DataFrame is built*.
How to do that depends of course on how you are building the DataFrame.

After the fact, the DataFrame could be fixed using applymap:

```
import ast
df = df.applymap(ast.literal_eval).astype('int')
```

but calling `ast.literal_eval` on each value in the DataFrame could be slow, which is why fixing the problem from the beginning is the best alternative.

---

Usually you could [drop to a debugger when an exception is raised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242485/190597) to inspect the problematic value of `row`.

However, in this case the exception is happening inside the call to `astype`, which is a thin wrapper around C-compiled code. The C-compiled code is doing the looping through the values in `df['x']`, so the Python debugger is not helpful here -- it won't allow you to introspect on what value the exception is being raised from within the C-compiled code.

There are many important parts of Pandas and NumPy written in C, C++, Cython or Fortran, and the Python debugger will not take you inside those non-Python pieces of code where the fast loops are handled.

So instead I would revert to a low-brow solution: iterate through the values in a Python loop and use `try...except` to catch the first error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['1.0692e+06']})
for i, item in enumerate(df['x']):
   try:
      int(item)
   except ValueError:
      print('ERROR at index {}: {!r}'.format(i, item))
```

yields

```
ERROR at index 0: '1.0692e+06'
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. I also tried converting everything to 'float' and it worked as well, even with the string as a value. A generic question though: is there any way to step into the error to pinpoint what value (or current index) is breaking? Tnx

Comment: I've added a suggestion on how to find the problematic value (and index).

Comment: is there a more systematic debug mode that would allow pandas to report which rows fails in any exception ?

Comment: @FredericBazin, you could arrange for code to [drop to the debugger when an exception is raised](http://stackoverflow.com/q/242485/190597).
Or, using IPython, you could use its [%pdb "magic function"](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/tutorial.html#debugging) to start the debugger whenever an uncaught exception occurs. Once you are in the debugger, you could print the value of the current `row`.

Comment: @FredericBazin: Note however that this will only work if the value of the row is introspectable from the frame where the exception occurs. If you are calling a NumPy or Pandas method which runs Cython/C/C++/Fortran code which loops through the rows then the Python debugger won't allow you introspect the state of variables inside the foreign code. That is why in the code above, I made a crude simulation of `astype` *in Python* so the value of the row could be found from within Python.

Comment: Nice "low brow" solution!

Comment: @FredericBazin I added an answer which is more general

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same problem, and as I have a big input file (3 million rows), enumerating all rows will take a long time.  Therefore I wrote a binary-search to locate the offending row.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

def binarySearch(df, l, r, func):
    while l <= r:
        mid = l + (r - l) // 2;

        result = func(df, mid, mid+1)
        if result:
            # Check if we hit exception at mid
            return mid, result

        result = func(df, l, mid)
        if result is None:
            # If no exception at left, ignore left half
            l = mid + 1
        else:
            r = mid - 1

    # If we reach here, then the element was not present
    return -1

def check(df, start, end):
    result = None

    try:
        # In my case, I want to find out which row cause this failure
        df.iloc[start:end].uid.astype(int)
    except Exception as e:
        result = str(e)

    return result

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])

index, result = binarySearch(df, 0, len(df), check)
print("index: {}".format(index))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

To report all rows which fails to map due to any exception:

```
df.apply(my_function)  # throws various exceptions at unknown rows

# print Exceptions, index, and row content
for i, row in enumerate(df):
    try:
        my_function(row)
    except Exception as e: 
        print('Error at index {}: {!r}'.format(i, row))
        print(e)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it faster than loop?

Comment: @serhii-kushchenko `df.apply` is already syntactic sugar for built-in for loops; they have the same performance. `df.apply` is orders of magnitude slower than built-in numpy and pandas ops.

Comment: As far as I remember, in Python apply is much faster than for loops.

Comment: @serhii-kushchenko nope. https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-efficiently-loop-through-pandas-dataframe-660e4660125d

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way to find the bad guys:

```
df[~df["x"].str.isnumeric()]
```

It outputs all rows which `does not` contain the valid value in your column `['x']`.