# applying astype(str) on necessary column only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe say df, which has 900 columns. 
when I do `df.to_parquet()` it gives key error. You may go through the error below.Just to tell you all `"df.to_pickle"` works fine in my code

As a work around when I do:
`"df.astype(str);"` which converts all column into string and therefore `"df.to_parquet"` becomes successful

But but...
I do not want to convert all columns into 'str'. I just want to know what all columns specifically are causing issue. So that's my major concern.
Hope you all understand my question now.

---

```
KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.conda/envs/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in get_logical_type(arrow_type)
     68     try:
---> 69         return logical_type_map[arrow_type.id]
     70     except KeyError:

NotImplementedError: struct<>
```

Comment: Hello! Just a tip: to properly format the code in the question, you can select it and press `{}` button on the bar on top of the textarea.

Comment: As for locating which row / column raises an error, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660313/pandas-location-of-a-row-with-error

Answer (score 0):

Look at:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21228

For more specific answer, you need to provide more details about your dataframe(columns types and minimal reproducible example).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df.select_dtypes(include='object')`

More info here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

Then, run `.astype(str)` on each of the columns selected. That way, you aren't converting other columns into strings.

Comment: code patch available at link works fine for me. But how to get the columns which are really creating problem. code patch there just converts all objects type str. I don't think we are having problem with all columns which are objects type.