# How to stay inside the debugger after encountering an error?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

When I debug a loop, the debugger quits when it encounters an error. Is it possible to stay inside the debugger so that I can investigate the program's state right before the error?

For example,

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

for i in [1, 2, 3, 0]:
    print(2/i)
```

I would like to hit `c` so that the debugger keeps running through the loop until the last iteration. Then, instead of quitting, the debugger stays active so that I can look at what is the value of `i` that is causing the error.

Comment: "the debugger quits when it encounters." - encounters what?

Comment: `python -m pdb -c continue myscript.py` :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242485/starting-python-debugger-automatically-on-error would help

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`pdb.post_mortem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem).  The code that may fail should be encapsulated in a try/except block, with the handler invoking that function, for example:

```
try:
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 0]:
        print(2/i)
except Exception:
    import pdb
    pdb.post_mortem()
```

Execution:

```
2.0
1.0
0.6666666666666666
> (3)<module>()
-> print(2/i)
(Pdb)
```

The pdb shell is now at the point of failure.